# Sorting GridView on code behind. Gridview generated dynamically. OnSorting method not been called

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, exception, gridview

I need to create a lot of `GridView`s to show on an aspx page.

Then, I've created a method to generate these `GridView`s, based on an array of names and `DataTable`s.

Anyway, each `GridView` is generated as follows:

```
GenerateGridView(string gvName, DataTable dtGridView){
GridView Gview = new GridView();
Gview.ID = gvName;
Gview.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
Gview.CssClass = "table table-responsive table-condensed table-striped table-bordered";
Gview.CellPadding = 4;
Gview.GridLines = 0;
Gview.AllowPaging = false;
Gview.Attributes.Add("Font-Size", "Smaller");
Gview.Attributes.Add("HeaderStyle-Font-Size", "Small");
Gview.AllowSorting = true;
}
```

Problem: I need the `OnSorting` method. But I don't have all of the `GridView`s names, they will be generated dynamically (The Gvied.ID or gridview ID is generated dynamically based on table names from a SELECT command).

So I can't create a `protected void gridViewName_OnSorting` method.

The `Gridview` is generated smooth. But every time I click on a header, I get an

> System.Web.HttpException

sorting exception.

I created a generic Sorting:

```
protected void gvSorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
```

Then I added an attribute to all `GridView`s in `GenerateGridview(..)`:

```
Gview.Attributes.Add("OnSorting", "gvSorting");
```

But, I keep getting the Http Sorting Exception. I debugged the code, and, besides

> OnSorting = gvSorting

appears on the generated `GridView`s, that error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is add the `Sorting` method to the GridView in `GenerateGridView`

```
Gview.Sorting += GridViewAll_Sorting;
```

And create a sorting method for all the GridViews

```
protected void GridViewAll_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    //cast the sender as a gridview
    GridView Gview = sender as GridView;

    //get the datatable from viewstate (or another source)
    DataTable dt = ViewState["dtGridView"] as DataTable;

    //sort the datatable
    dtGridView.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression;

    //bind the data to the gridview
    Gview.DataSource = dtGridView;
    Gview.DataBind();
}
```